# Can system() return before piped command is finished

Tags: c++, linux, system, libc

I am having trouble using system() from libc on Linux. My code is this:

```
system( "tar zxvOf some.tar.gz fileToExtract | sed 's/some text to remove//' > output" );

std::string line;
int count = 0;
std::ifstream inputFile( "output" );
while( std::getline( input, line != NULL ) )
    ++count;
```

I run this snippet repeatedly and occasionally I find that count == 0 at the end of the run - no lines have been read from the file. I look at the file system and the file has the contents I would expect (greater than zero lines).

My question is should system() return when the entire command passed in has completed or does the presence of the pipe '|' mean system() can return before the part of the command after the pipe is completed?

I have explicitly not used a '&' to background any part of the command to system().

To further clarify I do in practice run the code snippet multiples times in parallel but the output file is a unique filename named after the thread ID and a static integer incremented per call to system(). I'm confident that the file being output to and read is unique for each call to system().

Comment: Have you found out why count sometimes is zero when you think it should not be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/system.html)

> The system() function shall not return until the child process has terminated.

Perhaps capture the output of "output" when it fails and see what it is?  In addition, checking the return value of `system` would be a good idea.  One scenario is that the shell command you are running is failing and you aren't checking the return value.

Comment: That's a good idea and I shall do it. However I can see that the file extracted as expected, which implies that the system command is completing successfully. My issue is why is the file initially empty when trying to read it after the system() call and then non-empty when I look at the file system.

Comment: I've accepted your answer since it mostly concisely answers my question about the behaviour of system() (piped commands **do** need to complete before system() returns). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`system(...)` calls the standard shell to execute the command, and the shell itself should return only after the shell has regained control over the terminal. So if there's one of the programs backgrounded, system will return early.

Backgrounding happens through suffixing a command with `&` so check if the string you pass to `system(...)` contains any `&` and if so make sure they're properly quoted from shell processing.

Comment: I've edited the question to be clear that I am not using '&' to background the command. Good point though.

Comment: @J.Chuchill: Are you sure, that there will be no `&` in the text to replace?

Comment: Do you mean in the text being piped to sed? Even if there was how would this be a problem? I don't think it would be interpreted by the shell as a signal to background the process, it is simply part of the input to the sed command isn't it?

Comment: No, I mean the sed script passed as command line parameter. If that text contains some ampersand that isn't escaped correctly it will background sed.

Comment: Ah ok - I can confirm that there is definitely **not** a '&' in the sed script.

Answer (score 1):

System will only return after completion of its command and the file `output` should be readable in full after that. But ...

... multiple instances of your code snippet run in parallel would interfere because all use the same file `output`. If you just want to examine the contents of `output` and do not need the file itself, I would use [`popen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) instead of `system`. `popen` allows you to read the output of the pipe via a `FILE*`.

In case of a full file system, you could also see an empty `output` while the `popen` version would have no trouble with this condition.

To notice errors like a full file system, always check the return code of your calls (system, popen, ...). If there is an error the manpage will tell you to check `errno`. The number `errno` can be converted to a human readable text by [`strerror`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror) and output by [`perror`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/perror).

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I appreciate your point and have edited my question to clarify.